# Show help about comment triggered jenkins jobs in gerrit

Tags: jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I have a gerrit - jenkins setup. Several jenkins jobs are started by a trigger based on a comment inserted to gerrit. The number of comment based triggers increases continuously. The project has a separate document with information what keyword in a comment executes what action.

It would be nice to provide a list of keywords directly in gerrit so developers do not need open documentation when searching for a specific keyword. Is there a way how to customize gerrit to show some hints when a user edits a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the [*Checks plugin*](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/checks/) - currently is active development. It is/will be a complete redesign of how CI will do checks and how users interact with the CI checks being run. I don't think there's Jenkins integration for this already other than (custom) Groovy scripting polling the REST API at the time of writing.

The UI will allow users to trigger, re-run checks without the need for adding some magic comment! :-)

It's currently deployed on the [Gerrit of Gerrit](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com) for purely optional checks:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So far (Gerrit 3.0.0) there isn't a way to do that.